# Nintex Forms 2010 - How to set a rule with multiple checkbox options

Tags: forms, checkbox

I have a Nintex form and one field has 5 checkboxes where the user can make multiple selections:

```
Please select all that apply: [] red [] blue [] green [] yellow [] purple
```

If the user makes any selection that contains "purple" then i want another field to show asking for additional information.

I currently have my question field in a panel and this is the current rule for that panel:

```
not(Colors == "purple")
```

Right now it works but only when "purple" is the only selection. I need a statement that says -- Only show if Colors[the checkbox field] equals any combination of choices containing purple.

What's the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 0):

`!inArray(Colors,"Purple")`

SharePoint puts multiple selection in an array. Just add this rule to each control and change "Purple" to your other choices.

Here is an example of a rule, if you want one control be selected if one of the two colors are selected.

`!inArray(Colors,"Purple") || inArray(Colors,"Red")`